# can a custom RelativeLayout exceed parents height when defined as parents height?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following structure within a view hierarchy

```
ScrollView
   LinearLayout (horizontal)
      - RelativeLayout (X)
         -LinearLayout
         -CustomView
      - RelativeLayout
      - RelativeLayout
      - RelativeLayout
      - RelativeLayout
      - RelativeLayout
```

Here is a sample of it in the xml

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linLayoutWrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1080dp"
        android:background="@color/white">
        <!--- note this include is a <RelativeLayout> -->
        <include
            android:id="@+id/dg_axis"
            layout="@layout/day_grid_axis"></include>
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/grayBorder"></View>
        <--- start of repetitive substructure which his higlighted in screen shot -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/sundayColumn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="1080dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </LinearLayout>
            <com.mynursesstation.views.DayView
                android:id="@+id/sundayDayView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/grayBorder"></View>

        <!--- repeat above sub structure 6 more times --->
    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

where the inner structure (X) is repeated for all other RelativeLayout siblings. The Linear Layout, RelativeLayouts

NOTE: (X) is shown highlighted in its unusual behavior in Red, where as its parent is the entire screen width and is delimited with the grey vertical line above it.

[image]

The RelativeLayouts would all be flush to the top of the Linear Layout if all of them were the same size (That is my experimental opinion which has yet to be proved). If one is bigger than the rest, then they by default align to the bottom. My question is, how can These children of the RelativeLayout's exceed their parent when they are defined by the parent? Could it be that I am programmatically creating views whose intrinsic heights exceed the height of their parents? What is android's official handling of this case? Does the view overflow like an HTML DOM element?

UPDATE:

On inspecting each RelativeLayout, my hypothesis that one of them exceeded 3240pixels was wrong. None of them do. Only there seems to be a top margin applied to some (Which would theoretically increase the height of its parent, being wrap_content) but it does not.

The definition of the RelativeLayout called CustomView, is a RelativeLayout within which are programmatically positioned relativelayouts. They are positioned within their parent as follows:

```
    int pixels = (int) (height * scale + 0.5f);
    pixels = (pixels + 4) / 5 * 5;
    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            columnWidth / maxConflicts,
            pixels));

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) relativeLayout.getLayoutParams();
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START);

    start = cal2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    height = start > 0 ? start * 44.000000000f + (start - 1) : start * 44.00000000f;
    height += cal2.get(Calendar.MINUTE) / 60.00000000000f;
    pixels = (int) (height * scale + 0.5f);


    if (offsetAmount != null){
        params.setMargins( (columnWidth / maxConflicts) * offsetAmount, pixels, 0, 0);
    } else {
        params.setMargins(0, pixels, 0, 0);
    }
    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

However there is never a case where the top margin of the `relativeLayout` above plus the height of the of the `relativeLayout` exceeds 1080dp. I verify this dynamically by logging the height of the `CustomView` `DayView` with the following code:

```
    columnHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
```

which always logs out as `3240` pixels which at a scale of `3` is exactly `1080dp`.

So this eliminates the possibility that one of the `DayView` exceeds 1080 and that is why not all the children of the top level `LinearLayout` are not flush to its top. However, I still cannot comprehend what could be causing this behavior. All elements programmatically added to the DayView are `alignTop` to their parent and are positioned with a vertically margin which, with the height of the view being programmatically added` never exceeds 1080dp.

Notice that the red views have a mysterious mTop added even though their dynamic height is 1080dp. mTop + 1080dp > 1080dp yet there parent is 1080dp (it is wrap_content) !

Take a good look at the view which is flush. It also has the same height but has a zero mTop. I don't understand why this is or how can be possible.
[image]
enter image description here

UPDATE Saturday:

Good News! i have narrowed down the problem to a subview of a subview, which when omitted, does not cause this strange inconsistency in my layout logic / intention. The culprit is a `<TextView>` which is programmatically added to the two types of events which are programmatically added `<RelativeLayout>`s added to `DayView`. when both types of views have textviews added as subviews it breaks the view hierarchy. When only one is present, the views present as intended. Here is the code for programmatically laying out the calendar events the entirety of which consist of all the subviews of a `DayView`:

```
private void createEventLayout(CalendarEvent e, Integer offsetAmount, int maxConflicts) {
    final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int idForMyView = e.assignmentId > 0 ? e.assignmentId : -e.conflictId;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
    relativeLayout.setId(idForMyView);

    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    cal2.setTime(e.startDate);

    Calendar cal3 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal3.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    cal3.setTime(e.endDate);

    float start = cal2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    start += cal2.get(Calendar.MINUTE) / 60.0000000f;

    float end = cal3.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    end += cal3.get(Calendar.MINUTE) / 60.00000000f;
    float height = (end - start) * 45.0000000f;

    int pixels = (int) (height * scale + 0.5f);
    pixels = (pixels + 4) / 5 * 5;

    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            columnWidth / maxConflicts,
            pixels));

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) relativeLayout.getLayoutParams();
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START);

    start = cal2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    height = start > 0 ? start * 44.000000000f + (start - 1) : start * 44.00000000f;
    height += cal2.get(Calendar.MINUTE) / 60.00000000000f;
    pixels = (int) (height * scale + 0.5f);

    if (offsetAmount != null){
        params.setMargins( (columnWidth / maxConflicts) * offsetAmount, pixels, 0, 0);
    } else {
        params.setMargins(0, pixels, 0, 0);
    }
    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

    if (e.assignmentId > 0){
        // company name
        TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
        tv.setId(idForMyView);
        tv.setText(e.companyName);
        LayoutParams tvParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tvParams.setMargins(0,0,0,0);
        tv.setLayoutParams(tvParams);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams companyNameParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tv.getLayoutParams();
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        companyNameParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

        //time of assignment / conflict
        TextView tvTime = new TextView(getContext());
        tvTime.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        String startTime = sdf.format(e.startDate);
        String endTime = sdf.format(e.endDate);
        tvTime.setText(startTime + " - " + endTime);
        tvTime.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams timeParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tvTime.getLayoutParams();
        timeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, idForMyView);

        relativeLayout.addView(tv);     // ALSO this will break if present with the other kind
        relativeLayout.addView(tvTime);  // this too
        relativeLayout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.gradient_background_home));
        relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final int assignmentId = view.getId();
                if (assignmentId > 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AssignmentDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(getContext().getString(R.string.extra_assignment_id), assignmentId);
                    getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        final CalendarEvent event = e;
        relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.conflict));

        if (isConflictMode && e.isAllDay == 1){
            TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
            tv.setId(idForMyView);
            tv.setText(ALL_DAY_TEXT);
            LayoutParams tvParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            tvParams.setMargins(0,0,0,0);
            tv.setLayoutParams(tvParams);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams companyNameParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tv.getLayoutParams();
            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            companyNameParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

            tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
                    getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.calendar_small_font));
            relativeLayout.addView(tv); //THIS will break the layout logic
       }
    }

    this.addView(relativeLayout);
    return;
}
```

I tried making sure the `<TextView>` is clipped by its parent by setting

```
tv.setGravity(Gravity.CLIP_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CLIP_VERTICAL)
```

when I inspect it in the view it appears that it is clipping exactly to the bounds of the tv, yet, something seems to be exceeding the height of its parent based on the fact that when the `<TextViews>` are gone everything addes up, but when they are present, there seems to be too much vertical content.

Comment: Please post the xml code. Did you accidentally add padding/margin somewhere?

Comment: @Puneet do you want to see all of it because it is quite tedious and long and repetitive, but the structure is as shown above in the snippet. As for padding/margin, it would have to be applied to the <RelativeLayout> shown in red, which does not have any padding/margin applied as you can see in my snippet.

Comment: Please post the XML code down to one RelativeLayout and View child. Padding applied to container Horizontal LinearLayout can also add empty space.

Comment: @Puneet thank you I updated my response

Comment: My head is exploding with all the unnecessary nesting. Why don't you just use `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` for the repetitive part?  You have a `LinearLayout` without orientation at top, an empty `LinearLayout` inside your first `RelativeLayout`m and your custom view is creating another `RelativeLayout` when it can simply all be part of the first `RelativeLayout` inside `LinearLayout`. I will try wrap my head around your code while you consider `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` to simplify your layout.

Comment: 1) What is your DayView extending? (2) You never assigned `companyNameParams` to your textview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my problem was that i was assigning the same id to the `<RelativeLayout>` which was the particular `CalendarEvent` as well as to the children of this view, the `<TextViews>`. This created circular logic which referred to the parent and child which caused the views to not properly by aligned, I think specifically with the `BELOW` requirement of one of the textViews, being essentially made to be below itself. By creating a unique id with `View.generateId()` each time I created a `<TextView>` then the intended layout was made possible.